# Make VS2015 wait for precompile powershell script termination before continue build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015

I have in a .NET Core project some scripts executing at precompile state.

```
"scripts": {
    "precompile": [ "npm install", "powershell -Command \"./buildScripts/customscript.ps1 -Action build\"  -NonInteractive" ]
  }
```

When I hit F5 to build and then use IIS Express, the `npm install` is properly executed. Then the PS1 script is launched (I can see powershell window executing the `customscript`).

The aim of my `customscript.ps1` is to move some public files in wwwroot and is really important.

But **VS2015 doesn't wait for the customscript.ps1 to be ended properly before continuing the build process and IISExpress deployment**. So my static public files are not served properly. The name of the included files changes over time so a simple browser refresh doesn't make these files served.

**How to make VS2015 pause until `.ps1` script execution is terminated?** I want ps1 prevent, until terminated, the continuation of build process.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No... I use a CI to make my build and then it passes. But locally, I still have 2 steps.